# Natural electricity in the atmosphere - lightning

Tags: electricity, lightning, conductors

If air is such a poor electrical conductor, how can [lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) be produced that appears to travel through it?

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia's take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) on this?

Comment: A different way to look at it: if air were an excellent conductor, how would you produce lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you cite in your question has lots of detail on the mechanism of lightning, and I don't think there's much point in just retyping it here. However I wanted to pick up on Jon Custer's comment, because that's really the key point (Jon, if you want to expand your comment into an answer I'll delete this).

If air were a good conductor then we'd never get a charge separation between the clouds and the ground because the charge would just leak away, so we wouldn't get any lightning. If air had zero conductivity then the charge separation would never get big enough for a discharge between the clouds and the ground, so again we wouldn't get any lightning. We get lightning because the properties of air are just right. It starts breaking down and conducting at just the right field strengths for us to get lightning bolts.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm a little out of my depth when it comes to electricity and am just beginning to learn more about it. I didn't realise there was a link in my question. I'll have a good read of the article now.

Comment: @Seanosapien: looking more closely I see qmechanic edited your question and he added the Wikipedia link for *lightning*. Sorry, I assumed you had put the link in.